# Factorization of multivariable polynomial

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation, factorization

I have a multivariable polynomial, for instance: $P=yx+2^4xy+3+5^2xz+3^4zx $

I would like to do the following:

1. extract those terms that only have $z$
2. extract terms that only have $y$
3. express my polynomial something like this: $P=z(...)+y(...)+(some\  constants)$

I know it's quite easy but this is just an example what I want to do. In reality, I have a polynomial with 60 terms, so I would like to know the procedure for doing this.

Comment: tried [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Collect.html)?

Comment: Your example is bad since in fact the polynomial is 3 + 17 x y + 106 x z, which remains the same after vars = Variables[P];Collect[P, Rest[vars], Factor]

Comment: @ user18792 the answer to this example is straightforward and supposed to be $P=z(3^4x+5^2x)+y(x+2^4x)+3$

Comment: @ kglr  Thanks it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Collect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html):

```
poly = Inactivate[y x + 2^4 x y + 3 + 5^2 x z + 3^4 z x, Power]
Collect[poly, {y, z}]
```

> [image]